# Using javascript to read URL and apply if statement?

Tags: javascript, url, if-statement, innerhtml

I have a javascript portfolio filter on a page that sorts logos by category, it assigns a category anchor link to the URL.

I'd like to use this anchor link URL to trigger an insertion of text. I can trigger the insertion of text via onclick with no problem using:

```
document.getElementById("insert-text").innerHTML
```

This works fine, but when you click on category logo & go to new page, I want to be able to hit "back" and still see the same results. The text insert disappears.

I was thinking something along these lines:

```
Get URL (with anchor)
if URL = certain category anchor
insert text
if URL = other category
insert other text
etc...
```

I think my logic is correct, but not sure of the syntax?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking to do is to save the state of a page so that when you go back to the page your browser returns to where you left off. This is what browsers use cookies for. Cookies are a set of key/value pairs that your browser stores and you can retrieve the values on. You could put a boolean in the cookie that signals whether your function has been triggered, on page load you can read the cookie and if it is set to true retrigger your function.

[W3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) has a nice writeup on cookies to get you started.

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4YNfS/) shows how you can expire the cookie logically.

```
document.cookie = 'ExpirationCookieTest=1; expires='+exp.toUTCString();
```